# Google Sheets - How to find penultimate (second-last) non-empty cell in a column?

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have a column that'll have dynamic filled in fields but will be empty for the most part. I want to find the difference of last two values found in a column but nothing I've tried seems to work.

Comment: Can you tell in advance type of values (integer, natural, real numbers), and their range (min - max)? Are non empty cells contiguous?

Comment: Assuming the column has numbers, the standard way to find the location of the last entry in Excel is `=MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,A:A,1)`. Once you have that, you can use a similar formula to find the location of the second to last entry, and then use those and `INDEX` to get the values at those locations. Those are Excel though, I don't know if they're available or work the same way in Google Sheets, but maybe it's a place to start. And excellent correct use of penultimate. :-)

Comment: the column will only have numbers under 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not beautiful, but it works:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A:A;NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)));ROWS(FILTER(A:A;NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))))-INDEX(FILTER(A:A;NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)));ROWS(FILTER(A:A;NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))))-1)
```

Assuming you have values in column `A`, filter out empty cells, return squeezed array last value by counting rows, return squeezed array penultimate value by counting rows and subtracting `1`.

Answer (score 2):

This will get the value of the second cell up from the bottom:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(row(A:A)*--(A:A<>"")-1)))
```